# Accès global object in twig

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I know that i can access global vars in twig by this way :

```
# app/config/config.yml
twig:
    # ...
    globals:
        myVar: %someValue%
```

and then i'm able to call directly `{{myVar}}` from the twig template.

but what i would like is to access the global object itself, (the parent object of myVar in this case). Is that possible?

In case you may wonder, my goal is to do something like this

```
<body data-global={{global | json_encode}}>
```

which would allow me to have access in javascript to all my global twig variable in a generic way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes and no.. All variables are registered in the special variable `_context`, but this includes **all** variables present in the template.

If it's no hazzle to you, I'd recommend to set all your "globals" in an extra array and then `json_encode` that array.

```
# app/config/config.yml
twig:
    # ...
    globals:
        my_globals:
             myVar: %someValue%
```

---

```
<body data-global={{ my_globals| json_encode}}>
```

Comment: yeah, context would probably be too messy to use. Your technic is a good idea, i'll use that, thanks